# Why is Turborepo's turbod folder not created in docker container?

Tags: javascript, docker, turborepo

When trying to run the turbo deamon (`turbo deamon start`) in a docker container, I get the following error message:

> WARNING  failed to contact turbod. Continuing in standalone mode:
> connection to turbo daemon process failed. Please ensure the
> following:
>
> - the process identified by the pid in the file at /tmp/turbod/81c87a445e492784/turbod.pid is not running, and remove
>   /tmp/turbod/81c87a445e492784/turbod.pid
> - check the logs at /home/.../.local/share/turborepo/logs/81c87a445e492784-xyz.log
> - the unix domain socket at /tmp/turbod/81c87a445e492784/turbod.sock has been removed
>   You can also run without the daemon process by passing --no-daemon
>
> ERROR  run failed: error preparing engine: Could not find the following tasks in project: deamon
>
> Turbo error: error preparing engine: Could not find the following tasks in project: deamon

**Install info**

- `which turbo`: /home/.../.local/share/pnpm/turbo
- `turbo --version`: 1.9.4

**What I tried**

- I looked for the `turbod` folder, but turns out it was never created on the system (even though turbo was installed the recommended way: `pnpm install -g turbo`)
- Looked for the logs at the specified location, but that folder was not created either. I.e. this directory does not exist: `/home/.../.local/share/turborepo`

**Question**

How can I fix the above error?